# Can't debugging android app on Hyper-V Virtual Machine using ADB: Error Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1

Tags: android, debugging, virtual-machine, adb, hyper-v

I'm trying to debugging (whith Visual Studio) my android app (using ADB) on Virtual Machine created with Hyper-V.

Through this guide (https://bitbucket.org/chabernac/adbportforward/wiki/Home) I was able to show visual studio (installed in the virtual machine) my device (Samsung S8) as a debugging device.

The problem is that when I start debugging from the virtual machine to my device (connected in the same wifi network) I get this error:

```
Cannot start debugging: Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:29308: 
No connection could be made because the target machine 
actively refused it 127.0.0.1:29309 
Couldn't connect debugger. 
You can see more details in Xamarin Diagnostic output and the full exception on logs.
```

On Xamarin Diagnostic output can't see anything that can make me understand what the problem could be.

Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must download latest SDK platforms tools Android.